# jQuery fullCalendar with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) in my Angular app, but it so happens that the calendar itself is not on the main page and needs to be rendered as needed.

I came up with a setTimeout() workaround, but I think there must be a better way and hopefully I'm not the only one who stumbled upon this behavior.

```
    // only the buttons are displayed, not the calendar
    $("#calendar-me").fullCalendar();

    // works, but haaacky!
    /*
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#calendar-me").fullCalendar();
    }, 200);
    */
```

Here is a full CodePen example: http://codepen.io/imehesz/pen/aOmaqZ

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/  It's based on (and requires as a dependency) FullCalendar, but it's already got a nice AngularJS wrapper.

Comment: I started a open source, fullcalender with Angularjs and laravel. You can see details there: https://github.com/avastamin/booking_management

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed quite hacky. I was fiddling around with `fullcalendar` a while back and got a a quite hacky solution myself before i found [ui-calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)

Comment: Seconded. Anytime you want to do something that has already done in AngularUI, opt to use AngularUI for ease of integration.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to use Fullcalendar with Angular.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        lang: "de",
        header : false,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDayDefault: false,
        hiddenDays: [0,6],
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "22:00:00",
        scrollTime : "07:00:00",
        //Events - loading from local DB
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
            //$scopes.dates from here
            //Callback returns dates in JSON-Format
            callback($scope.dates);                
        }
    });
```

If the callback is ready - for example when loading from local/remote database (NO MYSQL) is done - the calendar is refetching the Events. Same procedure when

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
```

is called. That construction creates a easy and working way to integrate FullCalendar into Angular without any angular-ui.